# divide list in to sub list if there is no entry for four days continuously

Tags: c#, linq, entity-framework-core

I have one list which has three columns. those are `CowID`,`DateOfMilking`,`NumberOfMilkInLtr`.

Now I filter the list by `cow id`. I want to divide the filtered list in sub list from all data if there are no entries for four dates continuously. For example, if there is no entry for the dates from `01-08-2018 to 04-08-2018` then divide list from here and so on.

Please give me some idea how to do this.

Comment: how about [TakeWhile](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb534804(v=vs.110).aspx)?

Comment: @vasily.sib `01-08-2018 to 04-08-2018` is for example. I don't have any static dates. I have to find those dynamically from list and then divide from there.

Comment: I mean: `list.TakeWhile(x => x.DateOfMilking - previousDateOfMilking < TimeSpan.FromDays(3)).ToList()`

Comment: @vasily.sib how we will get `previousDateOfMilking`

Comment: its up to you. At first like `list[0].DateOfMilking`, then inside `TakeWhile`. You are asking for _"some idea"_ and not for complete working solution, don't you?

Comment: @vasily.sib What about this
`list.TakeWhile((x,index) => index > 0 && (x[index].DateOfMilking - x[index-1].DateOfMilking < TimeSpan.FromDays(3))).ToList()`

Comment: first element will have index = 0, so your predicate (`index > 0 && ...`) will return false, and `TakeWhile(...)` will return empty enumeration

Comment: @vasily.sib thanks for the help. I will try practically

Comment: @vasily.sib maybe this will work `list.TakeWhile((x,index) => index == 0 ? true : (x[index].DateOfMilking - x[index-1].DateOfMilking < TimeSpan.FromDays(3))).ToList()` but will try with implementation

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's a start to a possible solution. Note that this unfortunately removes the 1st item, which will need to be resolved. But other than that, it does split the lists based on the 4 day gap

```cs
void Main()
{
    var data = new List<CowOutput> {
        new CowOutput {CowID = 1, DateOfMilking = new DateTime(2018, 7, 30), NumberOfMilkInLtr = 1.2F },
        new CowOutput {CowID = 1, DateOfMilking = new DateTime(2018, 7, 31), NumberOfMilkInLtr = 1.3F },
        new CowOutput {CowID = 1, DateOfMilking = new DateTime(2018, 8,  5), NumberOfMilkInLtr = 1.5F },
        new CowOutput {CowID = 1, DateOfMilking = new DateTime(2018, 8,  6), NumberOfMilkInLtr = 1.1F },
        new CowOutput {CowID = 1, DateOfMilking = new DateTime(2018, 8,  7), NumberOfMilkInLtr = 1.7F },
        new CowOutput {CowID = 1, DateOfMilking = new DateTime(2018, 8,  8), NumberOfMilkInLtr = 1.4F },
        new CowOutput {CowID = 2, DateOfMilking = new DateTime(2018, 7, 30), NumberOfMilkInLtr = 1.4F },
        new CowOutput {CowID = 3, DateOfMilking = new DateTime(2018, 7, 31), NumberOfMilkInLtr = 1.1F },
        new CowOutput {CowID = 2, DateOfMilking = new DateTime(2018, 8,  1), NumberOfMilkInLtr = 1.8F },
        new CowOutput {CowID = 5, DateOfMilking = new DateTime(2018, 8,  2), NumberOfMilkInLtr = 1.4F },
        new CowOutput {CowID = 6, DateOfMilking = new DateTime(2018, 8,  3), NumberOfMilkInLtr = 1.2F },
        new CowOutput {CowID = 2, DateOfMilking = new DateTime(2018, 8,  5), NumberOfMilkInLtr = 1.5F },
        new CowOutput {CowID = 1, DateOfMilking = new DateTime(2018, 6,  5), NumberOfMilkInLtr = 1.5F },
    };

    var cowId = 1;
    var days = 4;


    var cowData = data
        .Where(d => d.CowID == cowId)
        .OrderBy(d => d.DateOfMilking);

    cowData
        .Zip(
            cowData.Skip(1), 
            (current, next) =>
            {
                next.Group = (next.DateOfMilking.Subtract(current.DateOfMilking).TotalDays >= days)
                    ? current.Group + 1
                    : current.Group ;
                return next;
            })
        .GroupBy(d => d.Group)
        .Select(d => d.ToList())
        .ToList()
        .Dump(); // I'm using LinqPad to test this. You can remove this and just use the output.
}

public class CowOutput
{
    public Int32 CowID { get; set; }
    public DateTime DateOfMilking { get; set; }
    public Single NumberOfMilkInLtr { get; set; }
    public Int32 Group { get; set; }
}
```